Can I expect a redundancy payment when the 2 year anniversary of starting is within my notice period?
I'm being made redundant with PILON.  My 2 year anniversary of starting with the company falls within the contracted notice period.  Can I expect a statutory redundancy payment?

As you're in the UK I'd highly recommend speaking to someone at Citizen's Advice.

NAL, but I've been involved with too many redundancy situations, over the last twenty years, and been an employee rep on several of them.
Your service continues until the last day of your notice period, whether worked or as PILON, so if your two-year anniversary falls within this period, you should expect a redundancy payment.
If your employer says otherwise, you should take legal advice.
There's lots of stuff on the ACAS website, mainly for employers, but it's an excellent resource for employees, as well.
